# Reduce objects and nested objects : javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i have been facing coding issue while trying to reduce the data stream. Below is the sample code

Data is being filtered on the base of exchanges, now i need to filter out the pairs not given in pair array.

```
//data stream
var dataStream = {
  "Coinbase": { "pairs": { "ETH": ["USD", "GBP", "BTC"], "DAI": ["USDC"], "LTC": ["GBP", "BTC", "USD", "EUR"], "ETC": ["EUR", "BTC", "USD"] } },
  "Binance": { "pairs": { "ETH": ["USD", "BTC"], "DAI": ["USDC"], "LTC": ["GBP", "BTC"], "ETC": ["EUR"] } },
  "CoinCorner": { "pairs": { "BTC": ["GBP", "EUR","LTC"] } }
};
//allowed exchages
    var exchanges = ["Coinbase", "Binance", "Bitstamp"];
//allowed pairs
var pair = ["BTC","ETH","LTC"];

const filtered = Object.keys(dataStream)
  .filter(key => exchanges.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = dataStream[key].pairs;//do some reduction
    return obj;
  }, {});

console.log("data filtered:" + JSON.stringify(filtered));
```

I needed to reduce the result on the base of 'pair' array where including pairs only get to the object.

**Update**
Result must be

```
var dataStream = {
        "Coinbase": { "pairs": { "ETH": ["USD", "GBP", "BTC"], "LTC": ["GBP", "BTC", "USD", "EUR"] } },
          "Binance": { "pairs": { "ETH": ["USD", "BTC"], "LTC": ["GBP", "BTC"]} }
       };
```

If someone can help or give clue, i will be thankful. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Post what you're expecting the output to be.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli thank for the comment, sorry question updated.

Comment: @SuhailMumtazAwan - It seems your updated answer has been updated many a times. Can you please have one version of the requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var dataStream = {"Coinbase": { "pairs": { "ETH": ["USD", "GBP", "BTC"], "DAI": ["USDC"], "LTC": ["GBP", "BTC", "USD", "EUR"], "ETC": ["EUR", "BTC", "USD"] } },"Binance": { "pairs": { "ETH": ["USD", "BTC"], "DAI": ["USDC"], "LTC": ["GBP", "BTC"], "ETC": ["EUR"] } },"CoinCorner": { "pairs": { "BTC": ["GBP", "EUR"] } }};

var exchanges = ["Coinbase", "Binance", "Bitstamp"];
var pair = ["BTC","ETH","LTC"];

let result = Object.entries(dataStream).reduce((a,[k,v]) => {
  if(exchanges.includes(k)) {
    a[k] = Object.entries(v.pairs).reduce((ac,[kc,vc]) => {
      if(pair.includes(kc)) ac[kc] = vc;
      return ac;
    },{});
  }
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Or you can simply use a for loop with **Array.includes**

```js
var dataStream = {"Coinbase": { "pairs": { "ETH": ["USD", "GBP", "BTC"], "DAI": ["USDC"], "LTC": ["GBP", "BTC", "USD", "EUR"], "ETC": ["EUR", "BTC", "USD"] } },"Binance": { "pairs": { "ETH": ["USD", "BTC"], "DAI": ["USDC"], "LTC": ["GBP", "BTC"], "ETC": ["EUR"] } },"CoinCorner": { "pairs": { "BTC": ["GBP", "EUR"] } }};

var exchanges = ["Coinbase", "Binance", "Bitstamp"];
var pair = ["BTC","ETH","LTC"];

let result = {};

for (let exchange in dataStream) {
  if(exchanges.includes(exchange)) {
      result[exchange] = {};
      for (let p in dataStream[exchange].pairs) {
        if(pair.includes(p)) result[exchange][p] = dataStream[exchange].pairs[p];
      }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

**Edit**

Based on updated result required, you can try following. Please note, converting pair array into object helps in improving performance as it avoids using `includes` operation every time to search.

```js
var dataStream = {"Coinbase": { "pairs": { "ETH": ["USD", "GBP", "BTC"], "DAI": ["USDC"], "LTC": ["GBP", "BTC", "USD", "EUR"], "ETC": ["EUR", "BTC", "USD"] } },
  "Binance": { "pairs": { "ETH": ["USD", "BTC"], "DAI": ["USDC"], "LTC": ["GBP", "BTC"], "ETC": ["EUR"] } },
  "CoinCorner": { "pairs": { "BTC": ["GBP", "EUR","LTC"] } }};

var exchanges = ["Coinbase", "Binance", "Bitstamp"];
var pair = ["BTC","ETH","LTC"];
let pairObj = pair.reduce((a,c) => Object.assign(a, {[c] : c}), {});

for (let d in dataStream) {
  if(exchanges.includes(d)) {
    let pairs = dataStream[d].pairs;
    for(let p in pairs) {
      // if the pair exists in pairObj proceed to check in its value, else remove from object 
      if(pairObj[p]) { 
        // filter the values based on entries in pairObj
        let r = pairs[p].filter(v => pairObj[v]);
        // If there was existing value, update the object else remove it from object
        if(r.length) pairs[p] = r;
        else delete pairs[p];
      } else delete pairs[p];
    }
  } else delete dataStream[d];
}
console.log(dataStream);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please see the expected result, question updated.

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake. your answer is correct. Thanks for the value able help.

Comment: @SuhailMumtazAwan - Glad to help you

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be working, I cloned original data, just to be sure that I don't mutate the original data

```
var dataStream = {
  "Coinbase": { "pairs": { "ETH": ["USD", "GBP", "BTC"], "DAI": ["USDC"], "LTC": ["GBP", "BTC", "USD", "EUR"], "ETC": ["EUR", "BTC", "USD"] } },
  "Binance": { "pairs": { "ETH": ["USD", "BTC"], "DAI": ["USDC"], "LTC": ["GBP", "BTC"], "ETC": ["EUR"] } },
  "CoinCorner": { "pairs": { "BTC": ["GBP", "EUR"] } }
};
//allowed exchages
var exchanges = ["Coinbase", "Binance", "Bitstamp"];
//allowed pairs
var allowedPairs = ["BTC","ETH","LTC"];

var clonedStream = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataStream))

const filtered = Object.keys(clonedStream)
  .filter(key => exchanges.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    var filteredPairs = {pairs: {}};

    for(let p of allowedPairs) {
      filteredPairs['pairs'][p] = dataStream[key].pairs[p] || []
    }

    obj[key] = filteredPairs;
    return obj;
  }, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered));
```

The result is

```
{
   "Coinbase":{
      "pairs":{
         "BTC":[

         ],
         "ETH":[
            "USD",
            "GBP",
            "BTC"
         ],
         "LTC":[
            "GBP",
            "BTC",
            "USD",
            "EUR"
         ]
      }
   },
   "Binance":{
      "pairs":{
         "BTC":[

         ],
         "ETH":[
            "USD",
            "BTC"
         ],
         "LTC":[
            "GBP",
            "BTC"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i am testing it with large data sets.

Comment: @SuhailMumtazAwan how will answer effect large data sets?